# SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK (60) for a fresh Nix installation

Tags: nix

Fresh installation of Nix on Mac OS El Captain; I am getting the above error.

Simply trying to run `nix-env -i hello`. Curling other resources works.

Tried removing `/nix` and reinstalling, didnt help.

Comment: Is NIX_SSL_CERT_FILE defined?

Comment: @LnL7 It is not.

Answer (score 0):

My shell seemed to be culprit.

If you run into the same issue I recommend try cleaning your environment.